# I am trying to copy the artifacts from Jenkins B to Jenkins A

Tags: jenkins, ssh, copy, scp, parameterized

There is a artifact abc.txt in Jenkins B.I want to copy that artifact to Jenkins A.
Is there a way to copy that artifact to Jenkins A.I tried copy artifacts from another project option but that did not work as the artifact is present in a different Jenkins server.

I am using Parameterized Remote Trigger plugin from Jenkins A to run a job in Jenkins B. That job will yield artifact abc.txt. This artifact I need to run one job in Jenkins A.

The Plugin used here is parameterised Remote trigger plugin.Jenkins A has been configured with Job A and Job B.Both jobs run in a separate Jenkins server.The artifact of Job A is abc.txt which is needed for Job B to execute.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue.I never expected that I will not get even a single response.

Comment: How do you resolve this issue if I may?